# Setup a multisite to a running website

Tags: multisite

I am trying to add a multisite to add another website in a diferent language. I followed the codex guide to config the multisite feature with subdomain.

I enabled the multisite network on my main website (http://example.com) added subdomain (http://pt.example.com) pointing to another directory.

I got confused after this step. I installed a new wordpress on this directory with new database, enabled the multisite on wp-config.php but the new site do not have the sites network enabled, instead is asking for a new install of multisite feature in where should be my new website like http://en.example.com, but I already have this feature enabled on the main website (http://example.com)

I tried to point to different paths but got 404 errors.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I enabled the multisite network on my main website (http://example.com) added subdomain (http://pt.example.com) pointing to another directory. I got confused after this step. I installed a new wordpress on this directory with new database

A multisite WordPress installation shares a single copy of the WordPress files, and a single database. Each site within the network gets a separate set of tables in the database, but it's the same WordPress installation.

You should **not** create a separate folder and reinstall WordPress as you did. You should create the new "site" on the main WordPress installation and configure it (as it sounds like you did), then point your DNS for the subdomain to the same host (or virtual host) as your main WordPress installation.